# How do I open a React Native Application on Expo Client?

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, android-emulator

I created an application using "react-native init MyProject" in Node.js command line . I want to open this application on my physical android device and not in my Android Studio emulator , I have installed Expo Client and I have tried "npm run start" and "react-native run android" but the application doesn't open on my device instead it appears in the Android Studio Emulator . **Do I need to initialize a project with "expo init projectname" for it to work on my android device ?**

Comment: If you want to use expo you need expo related files and configurations. To make it easier for yourself; if you want to use expo, initialize the project with `expo init ProjectName` like you mentioned. If you want to use react-native-cli, initialize the project with `npx react-native init ProjectName`. I recommend you to read through the documentation https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.61/getting-started.

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a react-native app in your phone, you will need to enable the Android development mode in your phone. You can do this following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options).

After you connect your phone in the computer with USB and run:

```
npx react-native run-android
```